# Is there any way to parse JSON with trailing commas in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm currently coding a transition from a system that used hand-crafted JSON files to one that can automatically generate the JSON files.  The old system works; the new system works; what I need to do is transfer data from the old system to the new one.

The JSON files are used by an iOS app to provide functionality, and have never been read by our server software in Ruby On Rails before.  To convert between the original system and the new system, I've started work on parsing the existing JSON files.

The problem is that one of my first two sample files has trailing commas in the JSON:

```
{ "sample data": [1, 2, 3,] }
```

This apparently went through just fine with the iOS app, because that file has been in use for a while.  Now I need some way to parse the data provided in the file in my Ruby on Rails server, which (quite rightfully) throws an exception over the illegal trailing comma in the JSON file.

I can't just JSON.parse the code, because the parser, quite rightfully, rejects it as invalid JSON.  Is there some way to parse it -- either an option I can pass to JSON.parse, or a gem that adds something, etc etc?  Or do I need to report back that we're going to have to hand-fix the broken files before the automated process can process them?

Edit:

Based on comments and requests, it looks like some additional data is called for.  The JSON files in question are stored in .zip files on S3, stored via ActiveStorage.  The process I'm writing needs to download, unpack, and parse the zip files, using the 'manifest.json' file as a key to convert the archived file into a database structure with multiple, smaller files stored on S3 instead of a single zip that contains everything.  A (very) long term goal is for clients to stop downloading a unitary zip file, and instead download the files individually.  The first step towards that is to break the zip files up on the *server*, which means the server needs to read in the zip files.  A more detailed sample of the data follows.  (Note that the structure contains several design decisions I later came to regret; one of the original ideas was to be able to re-use files rather than pack multiple copies of the same identical file, but YAGNI bit me in the rear there)

The following includes comments that are not legal in JSON format:

```
{
  "defined_key": [
    {
      "name": "Object_with_subkeys",
      "key": "filename",
      "subkeys": [
        {
          "id":"1"
        },
        {
          "id":"2"
        },
        {
          "id":"3" // references to identifier on another defined key
        }, // Note trailing comma
      ]
    }
  ],
  "another_defined_key":[
    {
      "identifier": "should have made parent a hash with id as key instead of an array",
      "data":"metadata",
      "display_name":"Names: Can be very arbitrary",
      "user text":"Wait for the right {moment}", // I actually don't expect { or } in the strings, but they're completely legal and may have been used
      "thumbnail":"filename-2.png",
      "video-1":"filename-3.mov"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Oh that sounds irritating.

Comment: I'm sure you can solve this in Ruby, but if not, it's fairly easy to write a JavaScript program (for instance, to run in Node.js) to fix the files for you: `const { readFile, writeFile } = require("fs");

const [, , sourceFile, destFile] = process.argv;

readFile(sourceFile, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    writeFile(destFile, JSON.stringify(eval(`(${data})`)), "utf8", (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
});` ([On pastebin](https://pastebin.com/D70MNjLj)) Usage: `node fixjson.js badfile goodfile`.

Comment: That works (in modern versions of Node) because trailing commas are valid JavaScript, and JSON is (in modern environments) valid JavaScript, so that code reads the file, evaluates it as JavaScript, then outputs the result as (correct) JSON. If you want to update the file in place, just get rid of `destFile` and replace it with `sourceFile` in the `writeFile` call.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the files in question are stored in zip archives on S3, identified by ActiveStorage blob identifiers contained in a Postgres database used to run a Ruby-On-Rails server.

Porting the conversion process out to Javascript would be...  non-trivial.  (Edit:  Unless I run the Javascript from within Ruby, which *might* be doable...)

Comment: Ah, well. :-) Hopefully you don't have to resort to that, but if so, easy enough (for a JavaScripter who knows Node.js) to create version of the above that reads from `process.stdin` and writes to `process.stdout` to make it easy to pipe the data through it. Anyway, hope you find a Ruby solution!

Comment: Have you tried https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval? it is risky though(possible command injection)

Comment: @SujanAdiga - *"Evaluates the Ruby expression(s) in string."* Is JSON a valid **Ruby** expression? (I don't do Ruby.) Seems...unlikely.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually, while the JSON spec itself is *not* a standard ruby expression, it comes close enough that I may be able to cheat it with some regexes.  Since `{"a": "b"}` *is* a valid ruby expression, even though `{"a" : "b"}` isn't... it might be possible.  Tricky as hell, but possible.  And since we control the source files, we know there aren't any injections in them, making a Kernal#eval call...  less of a bad idea.

Comment: Also, you will have to handle NULL to nil conversation.

Comment: Can you add more examples to your question that span the range of conversions necessary? If it's just the trailing commas in arrays that need to be removed could you just use a simple regex: `str.gsub(/,(?= *\])/, '')` ("match a comma followed by zero or more spaces then a right bracket)? If it's a problem with hashes as well (`{ :a=>1,:b=>2, }
 #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}`), make the regex `/,(?= *(?:\]|\}))/`. `NULL` to `nil` is easily done with a regex of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your are trying to parse something that looks a lot like JSON but is not actually JSON as defined by the spec.

> Arrays- An  array  structure  is  a  pair  of  square  bracket  tokens  surrounding  zero  or  more values.  The values are separated by commas.

Since you have a trailing comma another value is also expected and most JSON parsers will raise an error due to this violation

All that being said [`json-next`](https://github.com/json-next/json-next) will parse this appropriately maybe give that a shot.

It can parse JSON like representations that completely violate the JSON spec depending on the flavor you use. (HanSON, SON, JSONX as defined in the gem)

Example:

```
json = "{ \"sample data\": [1, 2, 3,] }")
require 'json/next'
HANSON.parse(json)
#=> {"sample data"=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

but the following is equivalent and completely violates spec

```
JSONX.parse("{ \"sample data\": [1 2 3] }")
#=> {"sample data"=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

So if you choose this route do not expect to use this to validate the JSON data or structure in any fashion and you could end up with unintended results.